# Safely remove harddrive in the GUI (equivalent to udisksctl?)

Tags: unity, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd, udisks

I have a toshiba hardrive that has a little blue light when powered and you can feel the drive spinning when powered. 
In Ubuntu I can mount and dismount by right-clicking on it in the Unity bar, but this does NOT turnoff the drive.

The only way I found to turn it off is this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178638/eject-safely-remove-vs-umount

What is the equivalent in Unity?

Comment: Unity is the Desktop Environment (actually a heavily modified Gnome and a Compiz plugin). There's no equivalent being the point I'm trying to get trough with the introduction.

Comment: Well, shouldn't there be? There is a tool that allows to do this, udisks, why doenst unity provide a button for this?

Comment: It doesn't provide "buttons" to everything, like any DE.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure other do... And I even think Unity use to provide that button... I've been using Ubuntu since 6.04 and I've seen this buttons before

Comment: If you're pretty sure then I'm sure you can give examples. Particularly of interest here is GNOME. If it has it in the vanilla version (I think not but you tell us) it should be possible to install it in either the new Ubuntu's Gnome or the former Unity.

Comment: I can't come up with a version number, If I know I wouldn't be asking. I don't even know if it comes and goes between versions or if there is some option I unticked and it disapeared. All I know is that when I bought the HDD a month ago and I tried for the first time, I could do it; otherwise I would have asked the question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently the button does exist (despite what was said in the comments of my question). Somehow, I did not update anything, I have rebooted a couple of time since then, it **just appeared**.

[image]

I didn't do anything special at all. Very unclear to me why this button reappeared. I tried unmounting first, and the button still appeared. I can't reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: In case of similar problems in the future you can use gnome-disks app ("Disks" in Dash). After you click a removable disk in a listbox to the left, there should appear a little "Power off this disk" button next to the settings button in the upper-right corner (this with a hamburger icon).